# Magento 2 Getting error when switching order grid to show 200 rows per page in admin

Tags: magento2, order-grid

In Admin->Sales->Orders, I can view orders with no problem, but as soon as I choose to display 200 rows, I got the following error,

```
Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state
```

[image]

I can fix this error by deleting records that is related to my admin user from the database table **ui_bookmark**, but as soon as I choose to display 200 rows again, the erros occurs again.

What caused this issue, and if there's a way I can fix this permanently?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error when the install does not have enough memory. Check your hosting settings.

`memory_limit` should be 768 mb +

Answer (score -1):

**Solutions**

You have to delete an order grid entry from the `ui_bookmark` table. In a `ui_bookmark` table, delete the row where you want to reset the filter.

or if you don't know which entry of order then you can truncate this table.

Comment: I did this, and it switch back and to 20 rows per page for me, and page get loaded. but as soon as I choose to show 200 rows again, it gives me the same error. so I can't show 200 rows per page?